Value of encrypting SAML Assertions
I have an auditor requiring us to encrypt SAML assertions from IdP to RP. I’m fine with this in general as it’s a pretty standard config and most SAML apps support it, but they claim it needs encryption when assertions pass thru an untrusted party and then give the users browser as an example of an untrusted party? Mind you- we’re not talking shared devices. We’re talking laptops dedicated to the user.
Is that a valid claim? How is it a risk if the users own browser can view the SAML Assertions?

This question might be a better fit on https://security.stackexchange.com/ See for example https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/204667/saml-assertion-encryption-and-using-same-key-for-encryption-as-signing
And why don't you ask the auditor as to their reasons?

"How is it a risk if the users own browser can view the SAML Assertions?" It becomes a risk if the user's browser is compromised, whether it be through a rogue browser extension, XSS attack, or something else. The increase in risk compared to an unencrypted assertion is that user identity and attributes might possibly be disclosed.

Unencrypted assertions allow the user to see  the data in the assertion.  That is often okay because the user knows most of the data in the assertion.  However, if there is any  confidential or personally identifiable data it should be encrypted.  Encryption only protects the data. The public key of the IdP allows anyone to create an encrypted assertion.  https://thehackernews.com/2024/05/critical-github-enterprise-server-flaw.html.  Unencrypted assertions are more common and likely better tested.  Adequately test that encrypted assertions are properly validated before implementing.
